# Tomcat stop responding

Tags: tomcat, server, configuration

I have created simple spring app which basically getting requests like '/user/{id}' and respond with data from database. I deploy it on local Tomcat 9.0 server. For entire week app works fine I can send request get proper response and it is great. The problem I have is that between 10pm Friday and 10pm Sunday (no one is using app) something going on and app stop responding at Sunday, until I restart the server. After restart it everything back to normal. Of course I was looking for help in google but just few posts have answers which satisfy me, but it still does not solve the issue. Could any one suggest what can be wrong?

I end up with server which run like this. That is only change I made for tomcat, plus add the admin account.

```xml
<Connector port="8070" connectionTimeout="-1" redirectPort="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1"/>
```

I appreciate any help, how to find solution or at least idea what can causes this issue.

Comment: How is the database connected? It sounds like an issue we experienced in the past that the SQL-connection times out and creating a new connection fails. That would explain why it happens on a day with no load. You should see related exceptions in the log, though.

Comment: So in the spring I am creating connection like this `Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
      databaseConnection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://servernmae:port", "admin", "admin");` and then I have bunch of methods which query database with `prepareSatement(stringSql)` So I am opening DB connection once, and querying it many times.